# Where to add an observer to the NotificationCenter in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa, initialization, notifications

I want to send a notification from a UITableViewController-A to UITableViewController-B.

I was adding the observer in the initwithCoder of the UITableViewController that is supposed
to catch the notifications.

The classes are correlated as folows

RootViewController
 ===NavigationController-A
 =====UITableViewController-A
 ===NavigationController-B
 =====UITableViewController-B

I need to add the observer before the views are actually loaded because notifications may be sent before the view is called.

However I have been told that initializing in the initWithCoder method in a UIViewController is not advisable, and was told to add the observer in the AppDelegate.

Are there any other suggestions for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement the Notification wiring in 'viewDidLoad' and then force the loading of both view controllers.  To force the views to load, get 'UITableViewController-A.view'.  It will see the view is not initialized and load the view from the nib, then execute 'viewDidLoad'.

Comment: Thanks that worked great!

I added a pointer of UITableViewController-A to the AppDelegate and associated it in the InterfaceViwer, then did [UITableViewController-A view] in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions( applicationDidFinishLaunching?) on App Delegate.